# Search nested db collection object values without knowing its properties

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I've the following collection structure:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "attribs": {
        "random1": [
            "value1",
            "value2"
        ],
        "random2": [
            "value3",
            "value4"
        ]
    },
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "attribs": {
        "random3": [
            "value5",
            "value6"
        ],
        "random4": [
            "value7",
            "value8"
        ]
    },
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "attribs": {
        "random5": [
            "value9",
            "value10"
        ],
        "random6": [
            "value11",
            "value12"
        ]
    }
  }
]
```

What I need is to get the rows where some of the values contains the text "1".

In the case above, would return the rows 1 and 3.

If I change the query to return the rows where some of the values contains the text "5", then I would get the row 2.

The query below does what I need, but my problem is because randomX is unknown and I can have hundreds of different keys:

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    { "attribs.random1": { $elemMatch: { $in: [/.*1.*/] } } },
    { "attribs.random2": { $elemMatch: { $in: [/.*1.*/] } } },
    { "attribs.random3": { $elemMatch: { $in: [/.*1.*/] } } },
    { "attribs.random4": { $elemMatch: { $in: [/.*1.*/] } } },
    { "attribs.random5": { $elemMatch: { $in: [/.*1.*/] } } },
    { "attribs.random6": { $elemMatch: { $in: [/.*1.*/] } } },
  ]
})
```

The following approach also solves my issue, but I'm concerned with performance:

```
db.collection.find({
  $where: function () {
    for (var key in this.attribs) {
      var values = this.attribs[key];
      if (Array.isArray(values)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
          if (values[i].toString().includes("1")) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
})
```

Comment: If you can change your data model (document structure), queries may be simplified if the structure was something like, `"attribs": [ { "name": "randomX", "values": ["value1", "value2", ...] }, ... ]`.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I know, unfortunately change the structure isn't a possibility right now.

Comment: I'd like to understand the downvotes here.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in how I fixed my issue after some research:

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $unwind: "$attribs"
      },
      {
         $project: {
            attributes: { $objectToArray: "$attribs" }
         }
      },
      {
        $match: {
          "attributes.v": { $regex: "1", $options: "i" }
        }
      },
   ]
).toArray()
```

Or in PHP/Laravel

```php
\App\Collection::raw(function ($collection) {
     return $collection->aggregate([
        [
            '$unwind' => '$attribs',
        ],
        [
            '$project' => [
                'attributes' => [
                    '$objectToArray' => '$attribs',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        [
            '$match' => [
                'attributes.v' => [
                    '$regex' => '1',
                    '$options' => 'i',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]);
})
```